# ListView SimpleAdapter set RadioButton Checked unChecked

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a `RadioButton` in a list view I am fetching the data from server and assigning to the `ListView` but in the list view there is a `RadioButton` How can I assign check in `RadioButton`.

Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<..........)
{
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(ID,(((Node) node_list_variables.getDoc_id().item(0)).getNodeValue()));
    map.put(ANSWER, (((Node) node_list_variables.getAnswer().item(0)).getNodeValue()));
    map.put(QUESTION_ID, (((Node) node_list_variables.getQuestion_id().item(0)).getNodeValue()));
    map.put(DESCRIPTION, i+1+", "+(((Node) node_list_variables.getQuestion().item(0)).getNodeValue()));

    menuItems.add(map);
}

// Adding menuItems to ListView
// All filed data are not shown in the list KEY_ID is hidden
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,R.layout.certification_question_item,
new String[] { DESCRIPTION, QUESTION_ID, ANSWER, ID }, 
new int[] {R.id.questionText, R.id.question_id, R.id.answer });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

**`R.id.answer` is my radio buttonGroup Id**

Comment: you want to do this in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use an ArrayAdapter instead?

```
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatever_you_called_your_layout_file, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.whatever_you_called_your_layout_if_its_not_already_inflated));
    ListView theList = (ListView)layout.findViewById(R.id.whatever_you_called_the_listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, android.R.id.text1, theNameOfTheStringArrayContainingYourValues);
    theList.setAdapter(adapter);
    theList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    theList.setItemChecked(checkedItem, true);
```

Just make sure you have set the int checkedItem to the value of the index in your String[] for the item you want checked.